How to understand the partial derivative of a total derivative?
I am going through a thermodynamics course and there is a section with a derivation that I don't quite understand from a mathematical standpoint.
Ignoring chemical potential for now, the "natural variables" of $U$ are $S$ and $V$, where $U$ is internal energy, $S$ is entropy and $V$ is volume.
We have a function $U(S,V)$ and thus
$$dU=\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right )_VdS+\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right )_SdV=TdS-pdV\tag{1}$$
Side Note
$dU=TdS-pdV$ comes from a separate derivation considering the function $U(S,V)$ and defining $T=\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right )_V$ and $P=-\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right )_S$.
We have $S=S(U,V)$
$$dS=\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right )_V dU+\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right )_U dV$$
and we solve for $dU$
$$dU=\frac{1}{\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right )_V}dS-\frac{\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right )_U}{\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right )_V}dV$$
$$=TdS-pdV$$
Moving on
We can rewrite (1) for $dS$ as
$$dS=\frac{dU}{T}+\frac{pdV}{T}\tag{2}$$
We wish to determine how the entropy depends on temperature.

We can differentiate the expression for $dS$ with respect to
temperature at constant volume to obtain $\left (\frac{\partial
 S}{\partial T}\right )_V$.
Apply the derivative to obtain
$$\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right )_V=\frac{1}{T}\left
 (\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right )_V+\frac{p}{T}\left
 (\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right )_V$$
$$=\frac{1}{T}\left (\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right
 )_V=\frac{C_V}{T}$$

Mathematically, what is happening exactly?
In other words, why/how does $dS$ become $\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right )_V$?
Here is my current understanding.
$dS$ is the total derivative function for $S(T,V)$.
$dS$ is a linear function of $dT$ and $dV$ and this linear function is a function of $T$ and $V$.
That is, at each $T$ and $V$ we have a different function $dS$.
If we differentiate $dS$ relative to $T$ we are determining the rate of change of $dS$ relative to $T$ at fixed $V$.
Notation-wise, it seems we would have $\frac{\partial (dS)}{\partial T}$, which is a notation I have never seen before.
If this is correct so far, then it seems that $\frac{\partial (dS)}{\partial T}$ is written as just $\left (\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right )_V$.
But this latter step isn't very clear to me.
So my question is essentially how to understand what is going on from a mathematical perspective in this derivation.

I think (2) is incorrect since $$dS\cdot T/dT \neq dS $$

@EDX I can't tell if you are right or not but the course I am following (MIT's 5.601x on, coincidentally, the platform EdX) has equation (2) pretty clearly stated in text and in the video lectures. Actually, I just noticed there was a typo in (2). I wrote $dS=dU/dT+pdV/T$ but it is $dS=dU/T=pdV/T$.


is absolutely incorrect. It doesn’t even make sense to have the difference of two differentials be a function. Nor does what follows make sense. I took 5.60 at MIT in 1970-71, and I doubt the mathematical content has deteriorated to become incorrect.


@TedShifrin Typo. Should be corrected now.

This is better understood as differential forms.

There is no "partial derivative of a total derivative." Let's forget about differentials for a moment. We consider the independent variables $T$ and $V$ and consider the change in $S$ due to a small change $\Delta T$ in $T$ with $V$ fixed. Then we have
$$\Delta S \approx \frac{\Delta U}T + \frac{p\Delta V}T = \frac{\Delta U}T,$$
and so
$$\left(\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta T}\right)_V \approx\frac1T\left(\frac{\Delta U}{\Delta T}\right)_V.$$
The $()_V$ notation is to remind us that we are holding $V$ fixed.
In the limit, as $\Delta T\to 0$, we have
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V = \frac1T\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V.$$
You can think of this as a chain rule application, with $S$ a function of $U$ and $V$, which are in turn functions of $T$ and $V$.

In a system in equilibrium with fixed $N$, the variables $U$, $S$, $V$ are inter-related (constrained) so that if we draw the possible values of triples $(U, S, V)$ in the 3D space, it will not fill up the entire space but rather traces a 2D surface.

Example. In the case of monatomic ideal gas, $U, S, V$ are related via the constraint
$$ S = Nk_B \left( \log V + \frac{3}{2}\log U + \text{constant} \right), $$
where the constant term depends only on $N$ and hence is constant in our case.


This fact, in general, allows us to write any one of $U, S, V$ as a function of the other two, by interpreting the small patch of the surface as the graph of a function (called implicit function).
Then your relation $\text{(2)}$ tells that $S = S(U, V)$ as a function of $U$ and $V$ satisfies
$$ \mathrm{d}S(U, V) = \frac{\mathrm{d}U}{T} + \frac{p\,\mathrm{d}V}{T}. $$
We also know that $T = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} = \frac{\partial U(S, V)}{\partial S}$ is a function of $S$ and $V$, which in turn means that $T, S, V$ are also constrained by a single relation. This allows us to write
$$ S = S(T, V) \qquad\text{and}\qquad U = U(S, V) = U(S(T, V), V). $$
In particular, $S$ and $U$ can be regarded as functions of $T$ and $V$, and we do so from now on. This means that we can expand each of the differentials as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}S &= \biggl(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\biggr)_{V} \,\mathrm{d}T + \biggl(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\biggr)_{T} \,\mathrm{d}V, \\
\mathrm{d}U &= \biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\biggr)_{V} \,\mathrm{d}T + \biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\biggr)_{T} \,\mathrm{d}V, \\
\mathrm{d}V &= \mathrm{d}V.
\end{align*}
Note that $\mathrm{d}T$ and $\mathrm{d}V$ are linearly independent differentials. So, by plugging this to the relation $(2)$ to obtain
$$ \biggl[ \biggl(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\biggr)_{V} \,\mathrm{d}T + \biggl(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\biggr)_{T} \,\mathrm{d}V \biggr]
= \frac{1}{T} \biggl[ \biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\biggr)_{V} \,\mathrm{d}T + \biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\biggr)_{T} \,\mathrm{d}V \biggr] + \frac{p}{T} \, \mathrm{d}V  $$
and comparing the coefficient of $\mathrm{d}T$, we get
$$ \biggl(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\biggr)_{V} = \frac{1}{T} \biggl(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\biggr)_{V}. $$

Actually you can see it as a chain rule.
First $S=S(\cdot U, \cdot V)$ :
Mathematically :
So $$ \dfrac{\partial S}{\partial T}=\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial T}\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial U}+\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial T}\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V} $$
Concerning $dS$ :
Mathematically differentiating :
$$ dS=dU\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial U}+dV\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V} $$
So $dS$ remains a mathematical function dependant on $T$.
So
\begin{split}
\dfrac{\partial (dS)}{\partial T}= & \dfrac{\partial }{\partial T}(dU\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial U}+dV\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}) \\= & \dfrac{\partial (dU)}{\partial T}\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial U}+dU\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial^2 UT}+\dfrac{\partial(d V)}{\partial T}\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}+dV\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial^2VT}&\end{split}
You just stay in the differential function space by applying the partial derivative with respect to $T$. For instance a mathematical function as :
$$ f(U(T),V(T)) \ \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R^2}} $$
You get with $A$ the gradients matrix of $f$ with respect to each variable $U$ and $V$:
$$  df_{U,V} : H\to A(U,V)\cdot H $$
In physics $A(U,V)=A(U(T),V(T))$
So :
$$  df_{U,V}(T) : H\to A(U(T),V(T))\cdot H $$
And
$$ \dfrac{\partial df_{U,V}(T)}{\partial T}=g : H \ \to\dfrac{\partial A(U(T),V(T))}{\partial T}H $$
Which (function $g$) remains a differential function in its form.
That's for the math of what would imply a partial derivative of a differential.
Now see the other answer to get it to physical relationship that are more $\Delta$ than real derivative.
